# IOS: Scaling Images while Maintaining a Fixed Point

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontext

I am trying to draw an image such that point (X0, Y0) in the image is at a fixed point (usually center of the screen). I am using UIImage drawImageAtPoint (I have to use rotated and multiple images that cannot be scaled to  rectangle) on a UIView.

This means that the upper left corner (X1, X2) usually is not (0,0).

Now I want to scale the image (CGContextScaleCTM by S) but keep the image point (X0, Y0) in the same location on the screen.

If I scale the image by S, how much do I need to change (X1, X1) to keep (X0, Y0) in the same location on the screen>?

I have tried a number of transforms based upon other systems I have used but am not getting anything to work.

Does anyone know what this transform should be?

Comment: CALayer has an anchorPoint property (amongst many other things) that may be of some use. Check it out! https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html   Although I should note that UIImageView's have a CALayer, while UIImage's do not, so you'd be manipulating the anchorPoint of your UIImageView, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the transform and scaling as usually and then do this:

```
self.scaledImageView.center = self.view.center; //if you want the image in the center of the view
```

In the same way you can add its center to the center of any view.

Answer (score 0):

Probably zooming with the help of `UIScrollView` and `Gestures` would help you. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) where a guidance have been provided to overcome this issue.

Hope it helps!